# How to make Bootstrap Collapse Horizontally?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

```css
.panel-group {
  z-index: 100;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-100%) rotate(-90deg);
  -webkit-transform-origin: right top;
  -moz-transform: translateX(-100%) rotate(-90deg);
  -moz-transform-origin: right top;
  -o-transform: translateX(-100%) rotate(-90deg);
  -o-transform-origin: right top;
  transform: translateX(-100%) rotate(-90deg);
  transform-origin: right top;
}

.panel-heading {
  height: 100%;
}

.panel-title {
  height: 18px
}

.panel-title a {
  float: right;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 10px 300px;
  margin: -10px -300px;
}

.panel-body {
  height: 300px;
}

.cont {
  width: 100%;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  -webkit-transform: translateX(0%) rotate(90deg);
  -webkit-transform-origin: left top;
  -moz-transform: translateX(0%) rotate(90deg);
  -moz-transform-origin: left top;
  -o-transform: translateX(0%) rotate(90deg);
  -o-transform-origin: left top;
  transform: translateX(0%) rotate(90deg);
  transform-origin: left top;
}

.cont {
  margin-left: 400px;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />


<div id="accordion">
  <div class="panel">
    <div class="pink"></div>
    <div class="panelContent p1"> <strong>Section 1 Header</strong><br/> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. In iaculis volutpat quam, non suscipit arcu accumsan at. Aliquam pellentesque.
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="panel-group" id="accordion">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-heading">
        <h4 class="panel-title">
          <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseOne">
          Collapsible Group Item #1
        </a>
        </h4>
      </div>
      <div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse in">
        <div class="panel-body">
          <div class="cont">
            Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird
            on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table,
            raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-heading">
        <h4 class="panel-title">
          <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseTwo">
          Collapsible Group Item #2
        </a>
        </h4>
      </div>
      <div id="collapseTwo" class="panel-collapse collapse">
        <div class="panel-body">
          <div class="cont">
            Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird
            on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table,
            raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-heading">
        <h4 class="panel-title">
          <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseThree">
          Collapsible Group Item #3
        </a>
        </h4>
      </div>
      <div id="collapseThree" class="panel-collapse collapse">
        <div class="panel-body">
          <div class="cont">
            Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird
            on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table,
            raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I need to use collapse feature on Bootstrap horizontally. [Here's](http://jsfiddle.net/g7m2x65z/) a pen of what I was able to do. But I must set fix height so now it works somehow. But I need it to be responsive. And the width of the panel need to be 100% base on the parent width.

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to rearrange and rename some of your `div` elements. You have two identical `id`'s (`id="accordion"`), the first inside the second.

You should change the `id` of the first "accordion", and then separate it from the 2nd "accordion" `div` (add a closing `div` and an opening `div` before the element with `class="panel-group"`).

**IMPORTANT**: Do not change the name of the 2nd "accordion", because it is the parent element where the dynamic elements open!

Second, adjust your css file:

1. Add the following lines to fit your accordion to the page:

`#accordion{width:90vh;}` and `.panel{width:100%;}`

Add media queries to adjust

`.cont{width:...}`, `.cont{margin-left:...}` *and/or* `.cont{margin-right:...}` and `.panel-body{width:...}` properties to match different viewport-sizes.

The complete jsfiddle can be found  [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Rpad/g7m2x65z/2/).

HTML:

```
<div>
<div class="panel-group" id="accordion">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">
             <h4 class="panel-title">
                 <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseOne">Collapsible Group Item #1</a>
            </h4>
        </div>
        <div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse in">
            <div class="panel-body">
                <div class="cont">Text</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">
             <h4 class="panel-title">
                 <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseTwo">Collapsible Group Item #2</a>
             </h4>
        </div>
        <div id="collapseTwo" class="panel-collapse collapse">
            <div class="panel-body">
                <div class="cont">Text</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">
             <h4 class="panel-title">
                 <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseThree">Collapsible Group Item #3</a>
             </h4>
        </div>
        <div id="collapseThree" class="panel-collapse collapse">
            <div class="panel-body">
                <div class="cont">Text</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS-properties to change/set:

```
#accordion {width:85vh;}
.panel {width:100%;}
.panel-title a {
    ...
    padding: 10px 0px;
    margin: -10px 0px;
}
.panel-body {
    height:300px;
}
.cont {
    width: 45%;
    margin-left:400px;
    ...
}
```

**NOTES:**
You control the height of your accordion with: `.panel{width:...}` and `#accordion{width:...}`.

The width of the sliding panels is controlled by `.panel-body{width:...}`, and the vertically positioning of text in sliding panel is controlled by `.cont{margin-left:...}` or `.cont{margin-right:...}`